# Insert the result count number of days between two days in spreadsheet using google script

Tags: google-apps-script

How to put in a Cell the number of days pass from a specific date. For example:

Column1: 12/05/2013 18:00:00 Actual Days using Function New Date() Column2: The script will insert the numbers of days (Today - Column1) = 4

The script should be insert in the column 2 the number of days pass from today. Today is 16/05/2013 23:00, the script will insert 4. If possible due this?

I'll appreciate if you can help me.

That function was passed by friend but I think doesn't work because the date is not in milliseconds but the result in the cell should be number of days

```
    }
    function formatting2(event) {
      var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet(); // get the sheet
      var columnF = sheet.getRange(2, 1, sheet.getLastRow()-1, 1);
      var updateage = sheet.getRange(2, 2, sheet.getLastRow()-1, 1);
      var fValues = columnF.getValues(); // get the values
      var result = new Date();

      updateage.setValue(result-fValues)
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a possible way to get the result you want, I wrote it as a custom function, ie you have to put it in the the cell where you want it to appear in the form `=dayToToday()`

here is the script with a few logs and comments to show intermediate values.

```
function dayToToday(x){
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  Logger.log(sh.getActiveCell().getRowIndex())
  var refcell = sh.getRange(sh.getActiveCell().getRowIndex(),1).getValue();;// get value in column A to get the reference date
  var refTime = new Date(refcell);
  var ref = refTime.setHours(0,0,0,0)/(24*3600000);// set hours, minutes, seconds and milliseconds to 0 if necessary and get number of days
  var today = new Date();
  var TD = today.setHours(0,0,0,0)/(24*3600000);// set hours, minutes, seconds and milliseconds to 0 if necessary and get number of days
  var day = parseInt(TD-ref);// get the difference in days (integer value )
  return day ; // return result that will be in cell
}
```

---

**EDIT :**
if I understand your use case I suggest you abandon the custom function aproach *(that I never use since I don't like it so much)* and go for this solution that uses a timer trigger and/or a menu to update values in your spreadsheet in one batch.

(ps : sorry for not having answer quickly enough... too busy these days :-)

```
function onOpen() {
  var menuEntries = [ {name: "test function", functionName: "toTrigger"},
                     ];
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  ss.addMenu("test menu",menuEntries);//
}

// create a timer trigger that will call "toTrigger" every 15 minutes

function toTrigger(){
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var data = sh.getRange(1,1,sh.getLastRow(),2).getValues();
  for(var n=0;n<data.length;++n){
  if(typeof(data[n][0])=='object'){
    data[n][1]=dayToToday(data[n][0])
      }
    }
   sh.getRange(1,1,sh.getLastRow(),2).setValues(data) 
}




function dayToToday(x){
  var refcell = x;;// get value in column A to get the reference date
  var refTime = new Date(refcell);
  var ref = refTime.setHours(0,0,0,0)/(24*3600000);// set hours, minutes, seconds and milliseconds to 0 if necessary and get number of days
  var today = new Date();
  var TD = today.setHours(0,0,0,0)/(24*3600000);// set hours, minutes, seconds and milliseconds to 0 if necessary and get number of days
  var day = parseInt(TD-ref);// get the difference in days (integer value )
  return day ; // return result that will be in cell
}
```

---

**second EDIT**:

when using `var data = sh.getRange(1,1,sh.getLastRow(),2).getValues();`

the numbers in getRange are start row, start column, number of Rows, number of Columns so you'll have to gat a range that includes the columns you want and then use data [n][columnNumber-1] to get the corresponding value. (-1 because array start from 0 and columns count from 1 (A in fact but A is first column ;-))
if you need a variable reference then let me know because the function must be modified to accept 2 variables (a ref and another one).

---

**LAST EDIT** (I hope)

I changed some details... see [9] and [5] index corresponding to J and F

```
function toTrigger(){
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var data = sh.getRange(1,1,sh.getLastRow(),sh.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  for(var n=0;n<data.length;++n){
  if(typeof(data[n][9])=='object'){
    data[n][5]=dayToToday(data[n][9])
      }
    }
   sh.getRange(1,1,data.length,data[0].length).setValues(data) 
}
```

---

**update/edit**

result in hours (following request in comments)

```
function hoursToToday(x){
  var refcell = x;;// get value in column A to get the reference date
  var refTime = new Date(refcell);
  var refhrs = refTime.getHours();
  var ref = refTime.setHours(refhrs,0,0,0)/3600000;// set hours, minutes, seconds and milliseconds to 0 if necessary and get number of days
  var today = new Date();
  var todayHrs = today.getHours()
  var TD = today.setHours(todayHrs,0,0,0)/3600000;// set hours, minutes, seconds and milliseconds to 0 if necessary and get number of days
  var hrs = TD-ref;// get the difference in days (integer value )
  return hrs ; // return result that will be in cell
}
```

---

Comment: Hi Serge, regarding your Script. The value of days I needs to insert in the column 2. The sheet have around 50 rows and other more. The script should insert the result on the column 2 for each row. I mean if I have 50row the script should be execute for every row. For the moment I can not insert the result in the column. I don't know why is not working.

Comment: have a look at this [ss for example](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AnqSFd3iikE3dFRDb2NCX3NqMmdmYU5TclNsSXZOUWc&usp=sharing) (make a copy to be able to edit it)

Comment: If possible the script insert directly the solution into the cell without write any funtion in the colummn? as per my last comment

Comment: The script work fine, but the column 1 change every days sometime I change 10 row other all the rows and the result not change. I mean in the column where I put the formula =dayToToday() not update the number when I change the column 1. I'll appreciate your help.

Comment: The problem is when I modify the date in the column 1 the formula count day (=dayToToday) not update with the new date. :-(

Comment: But this simple formula =(today()-A1) is working perfectly and update the day automatically. I needs the same but using an script without formula. I can pay for it... I am trying to find other ways in forum but a lot of people have the same problem

Comment: HI Serge Inas, I try everything to do this script work every 15 min or OnEdit. But the script doesn't work... Only update the date around every 12 o 24 hors. My spreadsheet is updated every time I the script should be return the result most recently possible. I my case the reference cell is updated very frencuen... I will appreciate if you can help... I try to ask this in other forum in other page an you are the person who response 80% question.

Comment: Thanks So much work very well... Now I am trying to change the refcell is not the column A is the Column J.. For the moment I don't know why is not taking the column J... i will let you know if work with column j

Comment: you shoould extend the getRange to 10 columns and use data[n][9] as reference (= col J)

Comment: I mean my date reference is in the column J and I want to put the result in the column F... for the moment the script return error when I made the change

Comment: // create a timer trigger that will call "toTrigger" every 15 minutes

function toTrigger(){
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var data = sh.getRange(1,1,sh.getLastRow(),10).getValues();
  for(var n=0;n<data.length;++n){
  if(typeof(data[n][0])=='object'){
    data[n][9]=dayToToday(data[n][0])
      }
    }
   sh.getRange(1,1,sh.getLastRow(),6).setValues(data) 
}

Comment: I have 10 column the last column have the date reference. The script is counting the number of days between column A to TODAY. But In me case needs to change the column A to J and the result show be insert in the column F.

Comment: Serge, The script only work if I set the trigger is OnEdit using timming the script not run.

Comment: I tested here with a 1 minute timer and it worked... but onEdit is also a good solution anyway isn't it ?

Comment: The problem is my spreadsheet have 8 sheet and 15 user login and editing the sheet. I have 2 other script run in OnEdit, and the sheet something is slowly.. My question this script If i set to run every 15 min. The script will run in the active sheet for each user or I can indicate to the script for which sheet need to be run?

Comment: I test it... I a spreadsheet with 1 sheet the script work with trigger set in 1 min or more. But when the spreadsheet have more 1 sheet in my sheet with 8 sheet not work

Comment: Using 2 sheet the script didn't work... Meaby I need to specify for wich Spreadsheet & sheet's the script needs to be run in the script.

Comment: Please start a new question, this is becoming too long and out of subject.

Comment: Thanks. I create the following ASK [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16992771/how-to-run-a-this-google-script-automatically-on-multiple-sheets-in-the-same-spr).

Comment: He Serge, How can I get the same result but in HH or HH:MM. I mean if this script return 1 Day, the new funtion should be return 24,25,26hs... depend of the hours. If possible get the same but in Hours?

Comment: Thanks so much Serge... Now I am trying to get the same but in this format 2d 23hs 14min....

Comment: Please start a new thread with subject : how to display time in HH:MM:SS from a value in milliseconds :-) or even better search for an existing answer on the forum... I'm sure you'll find.

Comment: Thanks so much... Serge I have this script OnEdit [CLIC HERE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17100901/how-can-insert-result-value-to-other-spreadsheet-help-in-the-script) I want to save the same info but in other spreadsheet like history. Do you know if possible.. I try it but I can didn't it work to same it in another spreeadsheet-

Comment: Serge, good morning, I have more one question.... Column E have the value 25/11/2016 8:10:00 and in the column J the result is days between E and today. But the problem is in the middle I have other column that have a formulas, when run this script put the data but clear the formulas. That exist any way to avoid paste the data between E & J and put the result directly in row corresponding... I mean the solution work but in this case the column data and the column with result are separate some column with other funtions