# How can I run a google script automatically on multiple sheets in the same spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have the following [script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16600972/insert-the-result-count-number-of-days-between-two-days-in-spreadsheet-using-goo).

## Situation:

I have a spreadsheet with 10 worksheets and 15 users logging in and modifying it.

## Script Function:

> Inserts the number of days between two days in the activesheet in a specific column,
>   Script compare date from column J and TodayDay and inserts the difference in the column F.

## Problem:

> I can not run this script with using timed triggers. I want to run this script every 15 min for the concurrent sheet.

## Test Case:

> The trigger only runs with timing if I have only one sheet in the spreadsheet.
>   The trigger doesn't run with timing if I have more than one sheet.
>   The trigger only runs for more than one sheet if I set the same trigger OnEdit.

I need to run this script for all sheets or active sheet every 15mins because I have two other scripts running OnEdit. When I set this script also in OnEdit the spreadsheet turn slowly.

```
    function onOpen() {
      var menuEntries = [ {name: "UpdateAge", functionName: "toTrigger"},
                         ];
      var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
      ss.addMenu("Tools",menuEntries);//
    }

    // create a timer trigger that will call "toTrigger" every 15 minutes

    function toTrigger(){
      var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
      var data = sh.getRange(1,1,sh.getLastRow(),sh.getLastColumn()).getValues();
      for(var n=0;n<data.length;++n){
      if(typeof(data[n][9])=='object'){
        data[n][5]=dayToToday(data[n][9])
          }
        }
       sh.getRange(1,1,data.length,data[0].length).setValues(data) 
    }

    function dayToToday(x){
      var refcell = x;;// get value in column A to get the reference date
      var refTime = new Date(refcell);
      var ref = refTime.setHours(0,0,0,0)/(24*3600000);// set hours, minutes, seconds and milliseconds to 0 if necessary and get number of days
      var today = new Date();
      var TD = today.setHours(0,0,0,0)/(24*3600000);// set hours, minutes, seconds and milliseconds to 0 if necessary and get number of days
      var day = parseInt(TD-ref);// get the difference in days (integer value )
      return day ; // return result that will be in cell
    }
```

## EDIT: WORKING

Hi Srik,

Thanks so much Now is Working.

```
    function onOpen() {
      var menuEntries = [ {name: "UpdateAge", functionName: "shellFunction"},
                         ];
      var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
      ss.addMenu("Tools",menuEntries);//
    }

        function shellFunction(){
        var sheets = ['Sheet1','Sheet2','Sheet3','Sheet4']; 
        for (var s in sheets){
      toTrigger(sheets[s]);
        }
      }

      // create a timer trigger that will call "toTrigger" every 15 minutes

      function toTrigger(sheetName){
      var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('SHEET ID');
      var sh = ss.getSheetByName(sheetName);
      var data = sh.getRange(1,1,sh.getLastRow(),sh.getLastColumn()).getValues();
      for(var n=0;n<data.length;++n){
      if(typeof(data[n][9])=='object'){
        data[n][5]=dayToToday(data[n][9])
          }
        }
       sh.getRange(1,1,data.length,data[0].length).setValues(data) 
    }

    function dayToToday(x){
      var refcell = x;;// get value in column A to get the reference date
      var refTime = new Date(refcell);
      var ref = refTime.setHours(0,0,0,0)/(24*3600000);// set hours, minutes, seconds and milliseconds to 0 if necessary and get number of days
      var today = new Date();
      var TD = today.setHours(0,0,0,0)/(24*3600000);// set hours, minutes, seconds and milliseconds to 0 if necessary and get number of days
      var day = parseInt(TD-ref);// get the difference in days (integer value )
      return day ; // return result that will be in cell
    }
```

Comment: Why not use a spreadsheet function? You can calculate the day difference for each row without the fuss. Just remember to send the reference date and toda's date as a function parameter.

Comment: I can not use a formula Array for ex because the spreadsheet is under modification every time. When the activity on that row is completed we delete it. <br> Example: If we use formula someone need to drag the to the new row, to avoid any error or a complex sheet I use this script to automatically insert the number without any issue is someone delete the cell where the formula is. <br> Using Array formula but when you add new row the formula not drag automatically also using array. <br> For my case I can not implement a formula. If you have any suggestion plese let me know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no active sheet when your function runs as a trigger. The active sheet is applicable only when a user has the spreadsheet open. Modify your script to use `getSheetByName` and everything should work fine.

If you want this to work on multiple sheets, just call this function from another function..

```
function shellFunction(){
  var sheets = ['sheet1','sheet2',etc]; 
  for (var s in sheets){
    toTrigger(sheets[s]);
  }
}
```

And change your `toTrigger` function to receive the sheet name as argument.

```
function toTrigger(sheetName){
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ID OF SPREADSHEET).getSheetByName(sheetName);
  /* Your regular code */
}
```

Comment: Clarification: When a trigger executes, it does so as a completely independent process on the server, and does not know if a user has the sheet open. In the case of an onEdit trigger, the function receives an Event that includes information about the source of the trigger. A timer-based trigger does not get such an event. So, even if a user has a sheet open when the timer-based trigger fires, the trigger function will not know which sheet the user is looking at.

Comment: I want this:
When the user is logged to spreadsheet, the script should be run every 15 min. (Note: This script have more 2 user logged at time).

1-How can I modify this script to run for 10 sheet using getsheetbyName?

I will appreciate your help.

Comment: Srik, do you know How to Set this script to run for more one sheet in the same spreadsheet? because my issue if i use the getSheetbyName only take 1 sheet. I needs to run that script for 10 sheet every 15min.

Comment: There exist any way to say to the script run the following funtion only for the sheet 1,2,3,4,5?

Comment: HI Srik is return error "TypeError: No se puede llamar al método "getRange" de null.Ignorar" see my EDIT 13/06/2013

Comment: You have to update your onOpen to point to the shellfunction rather than toTrigger

Comment: In English is TypeError: IS not possible call to method "getRange" null" and other time said the same but for getsheetByName

Comment: HI Srik, Still getting error. Note: The script should be Run in the both way I mean from Menu and also Automatically from Time Trigger

Comment: or just from Time Trigger. I will appreciate if you can help me

Comment: How can I insert the Date&Time /NewDate()/ when the script run into a specific sheet an cell. I want to insert the date in the sheet9 in range A1 every time when the script run. Thanks in Advance

Comment: Everything is Working... Thanks So Much for Your Time