# How to test time-based trigger through multiple sheets in the same spreadsheet?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

First, I am creating a time-based trigger to run every day between 1am and 2am. I need this trigger to run a function across multiple sheets every time, without creating additional functions. I think I have it mostly figured out, but I am having issues testing it without running the trigger and then waiting until the next day to see if it worked. Is there a way to test the trigger without having to wait 24 hours for every change that I make?

Second, when I do hit run on `function shellFunction() {`, it doesn't seem to run the function I need to run during the function, which is `function dateChange() {`. I do know the `dateChange ()` function works properly, at least on the active sheet. I need help figuring out why it won't run the `dateChange ()` function when I run the script.

My code:

```
ScriptApp.newTrigger("dateChange")
    .timeBased()
    .atHour(1)
    .everyDays(1)
    .create();

function shellFunction() {
  var sheets = ['Screening','Maint - PrePress','Vulcan','Sullivan','Packing','Materials','Shipping','Labels','Embroidery','Pad Print','Quality'];
  for (var s in sheets) {
    toTrigger(sheets[s]);
  }
}

function toTrigger(sheets) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sh = ss.getSheetByName(sheets);
}

function dateChange() {
  var sss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = sss.getSheets()[0];

  // Move all filled columns one to the right
  var columnSpec = sss.getRange("D1:NG1");
  columnSpec.moveTo(sss.getRange("E1:NH1"));
  
  // Auto-fill to the column the new date is needed in
  sheet.getRange('H1:M1').activate();
  sheet.getActiveRange().autoFill(sheet.getRange('M1:C1'), SpreadsheetApp.AutoFillSeries.DEFAULT_SERIES);
 
}
```

The references I have used so far:

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/clock-trigger-builder

[How can I run a google script automatically on multiple sheets in the same spreadsheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16992771/how-can-i-run-a-google-script-automatically-on-multiple-sheets-in-the-same-sprea)

Comment: Although I went the extra mile to provide an answer. It is highly recommended your question to be focused on one (independent) problem only. People don't tend to answer questions with many sub questions as this is not a coding service platform.

Comment: Did any of the answers work for you ?

Comment: First, thank you very much for answering and I will keep that in mind for the future. Second, I thought the first question was sufficiently small that it would be fine, however, and again, I will split up such questions in the future.

Comment: happy coding, you are good

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Explanation:

> Is there a way to test the trigger without having to wait 24 hours for
> every change that I make?

The answer is quite simple. Time triggers are responsible for running functions on a timely basis. The function will run exactly the same as if you would run it manually. Therefore, you can test if your function works by selecting that function and executing and see if you are getting the desired result. If yes, then you can set a time trigger that executes that function for you.

> I need this trigger to run a function across multiple sheets every
> time

- `shellFunction` and `toTrigger(sheets)` are not used anywhere in your script. Namely, they are not called by the `dateChange` function which is supposed to be triggered.
- `dateChange` has two issues. Firstly it works only for the first sheet in your spreadsheet file because of `sss.getSheets()[0];` and also this part of your code will be executed for the active sheet `sss.getRange("D1:NG1");` which might not be the first sheet in your sheet. Also this is not the recommended way to do it anyway. Why do you want to run on the active sheet, given you have specific sheets that you want to use?

**General issues with your code:**

- Don't use active ranges, just get the range and use it. You don't
  want to see the changes as they are happening, especially given the fact that you want to
  execute the script via a time trigger (not manually).
- You define the trigger creation part as a global operation that will be executed anytime you run any function in that script. It is advisable to wrap this operation inside of a function.
- You only need **two** functions. One will be responsible for creating the trigger and the other one will be the main function which will run on selected sheets.
- When you iteratively interact with sheets and setting values etc it is always a good idea to [flush](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#flush) the pending sheet changes.

### Solution:

```
function createTrigger(){
ScriptApp.newTrigger("dateChange")
    .timeBased()
    .atHour(1)
    .everyDays(1)
    .create();
}

function dateChange() {
  var sss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheets = sss.getSheets();
  var sheet_names = ['Screening','Maint - PrePress','Vulcan','Sullivan','Packing',
                     'Materials','Shipping','Labels','Embroidery','Pad Print','Quality'];
  
  sheets.forEach(sheet=>{               
  if(sheet_names.includes(sheet.getName())){
    // Move all filled columns one to the right
    var columnSpec = sheet.getRange("D1:NG1");
    columnSpec.moveTo(sheet.getRange("E1:NH1"));  
    // Auto-fill to the column the new date is needed in
    const rng = sheet.getRange('H1:M1');
    rng.autoFill(sheet.getRange('M1:C1'), SpreadsheetApp.AutoFillSeries.DEFAULT_SERIES);
    SpreadsheetApp.flush();    
  }                                               
  }); 
}
```

- To setup the trigger execute **only** and **once** the
  `createTrigger` function:

  [image]
- If you want to test if the time trigger will work, then execute
  `dateChange` manually instead an see if you are getting the desired
  results in your sheets.

Comment: This answers everything I had questions on. It actually taught me some things I didn't know, such as about ```flush ()``` and putting the trigger inside a function. I realized it was creating multiple triggers, and I was deleting them occasionally, but I had not gotten to figuring out that specific issue. What really gets me about your answer is that it seems I had all the necessary bits, just not in the right order or locations.      A question though, is sheet it's own class?

Comment: @JedBurch yes [sheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet) is a class.

Answer (score 0):

**1. As the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/clock-trigger-builder) specifies - apart from `everyDas(n)` there are also methods like [everyHours(n)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/clock-trigger-builder#everyhoursn) or [everyMinutes(n)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/clock-trigger-builder#everyminutesn) that allow you to fire the trigger more often**

- So for testing purposes, delete you current trigger (e.g. by going on `Edit-> Current project's triggers` and then right-click on the trigger and delete it:

---

[image]

---

- Then create a new trigger either via UI:

---

[image]

---

- Or programamtically with

```js
ScriptApp.newTrigger("dateChange")
  .timeBased()
  .everyMinutes(1)
  .create();
```

**This is for testing purposes - once you verify that your Script works - delete the minute trigger and install the daily trigger back in the same way.**

**2. To understand why your function does not execute**

- implement logs at different parts of your function and then go on `View->Executions` to see either the trigger has run correctly - and if not, at what position it failed

Sample function with logs:

```js
function dateChange() {
  Logger.log("testlog at the beginning");
  var sss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = sss.getSheets()[0];
  
  // Delete C column and then reinsert blank C Column
  //sheet.deleteColumn(3);
  //sheet.insertColumnsBefore(3,1)
  
  // Move all filled columns one to the right
  var columnSpec = sss.getRange("D1:NG1");
  columnSpec.moveTo(sss.getRange("E1:NH1"));
  Logger.log("testlog after moving");
  
  // Auto-fill to the column the new date is needed in
  sheet.getRange('H1:M1').activate();
  sheet.getActiveRange().autoFill(sheet.getRange('M1:C1'), SpreadsheetApp.AutoFillSeries.DEFAULT_SERIES);
  Logger.log("testlog after autofill");  
}
```

Sample execution logs:

---

[image]

---

Comment: I think for testing a function generally it is a good practice to just execute it. If we needed a time trigger to test our functions then programming would be a nightmare. Also that was the smallest issue in his approach I believe.

Comment: The question was " Is there a way to test the trigger without having to wait 24 hours for every change that I make?" After all there are many constellations when a function works when ran manually from the editor, but not when fired on a time-based trigger, so it is important to test the functionalities of triggers.

Comment: you are right that is true.

Comment: @ziganotschka I will use that while testing for further functionality. Appreciate it.