# How to Insert Result of SUM from Two Date in the spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

How to Insert Result of SUM from Two Date in the spreadsheet

Data:

- H3: `27/11/2013 1:31:00`
- F3: `00:15`
- I3: Should be appear the result of SUM (H3+F3) using this formula `=SUM(H3+F3)`. The Result is `27/11/2013 1:49:00` (24hs Formatting)

## Action:

1. Should be executed only when some insert a value in the column F starting 3rd row.
2. Only should be executed for the row where was modify.
3. Should be insert the result in column I, the sum of H+F

Here I have the starting script for the 1 & 2.

```
function CreationDate(event){
  //Script Sume Date

  var actSht = event.source.getActiveSheet();
  if (actSht.getName() == "sheet1"){
  var activeCell = actSht.getActiveCell(); //Detec the ActiveCell

  var column = activeCell.getColumn(); // Detect the Column of the ActiveCell
  var colNums  = [6]; //Coulmns, whose edit is considered
  if(colNums.indexOf(column) == -1) return; //If column other than considered then return

  var row = activeCell.getRow(); //Detect the ActiveRow
  if(row < 3)   return; //If header row then return
```

## TEST:

I try to formatting this script [Clic Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16600972/insert-the-result-count-number-of-days-between-two-days-in-spreadsheet-using-goo) to sum the data and back the result in dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss but I didn't have lucky.

## Why is needed?:

Is very important have this formula run asap because I use is to scheduling a critical call to many ISP around the country.

I try to use `=arrayformula(sum(h3+f3))` but didn't work. I needs a script because I add new rows all the time.

I will appreciate your help.

Best Regards,

Comment: If the data starts in row 3, then the array formula solution in `I3` would be `=ArrayFormula(IF(ISNUMBER(H3:H)*ISNUMBER(F3:F);H3:H+F3:F;IFERROR(1/0)))`

Comment: Thanks So much... your workaround is working... I'll still working or try to find someone to help to developer the formula in script. 
The problem this sheet is used for many user and anyone can delete the formula.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The single-row version of Adam's formula, in row 3 for example, is:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(H3)*ISNUMBER(F3);H3+F3;IFERROR(1/0))
```

Since you're worried that users may damage the formula, you can use an onEdit() trigger function to ensure the formula is updated in Column I anytime the data in Column F is edited.

```
// When a value is entered in column F, set I = H + F, for rows >= 3.
function onEdit(e) {
  if (!e) {  // This block is for testing in debugger; always uses row 3
    e = {};
    e.range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('F3');
    e.value = e.range.getValue();
  }
  var row = e.range.getRow();
  var col = e.range.getColumn();

  if (col == 6 && row >= 3) {
    // Insert single-cell version of Adam's formula into I
    e.range.getSheet().getRange(row,9)
     .setFormula('=IF(ISNUMBER(H'+row+')*ISNUMBER(F'+row+');H'+row+'+F'+row+';IFERROR(1/0))');
  }
}
```

An alternative way to insert the correct row number into the formula is to use Regular Expression replacement:

```
...
// Insert single-cell version of Adam's formula into I
var rowTag = new RegExp('%ROW%','g');
var formula = '=IF(ISNUMBER(H%ROW%)*ISNUMBER(F%ROW%);H%ROW%+F%ROW%;IFERROR(1/0))'
            .replace(rowTag,row);
e.range.getSheet().getRange(row,9).setFormula(formula);
...
```

Comment: And yet another way is to use whole-column references without the ArrayFormula wrap; cells on the same row as the formula will automatically be referenced: `.setFormula('=IF(ISNUMBER(H:H)*ISNUMBER(F:F);H:H+F:F;IFERROR(1/0))');`

Comment: THANKS TO ALL IS WORKING VERY WELL!!! I use the script for Mogsdad and the setFormula from AdamL... Thanks to much....